# Evaluate $\int_L \vec F\cdot \vec{dr} $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $$\int_L \vec F\cdot \vec{dr} $$
>
> Where $L:\{(x,y,z):x=3\cos t, y=4\sin t,z=t^2\}$ from $(3,0,0)$ to $(0,4,\frac{\pi^2}{4})$
>
> Where $\vec F=yz(2x+y+z)\hat i+xz(x+2y+z)\hat j+xy(x+y+2z)\hat k$

*Attempt:*

$$-3\leqslant x \leqslant 3,\quad -4\leqslant y\leqslant  4,\quad -\infty \leqslant z \leqslant +\infty$$

This looks like "elliptic string"

I'm not so sure what should I do next, I have an exam in a few days

Maybe Stokes's theorem?

Comment: Let $\vec \gamma(t) = 3\cos(t)\hat i + 4\sin(t)\hat j +t^2\hat k$.  Then $$\int_L \vec F\cdot d\vec r = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}\vec F(\vec \gamma(t))\cdot \vec\gamma'(t)\ dt$$ where the RHS is just a regular Riemann integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral $\int_L \vec F\cdot d\vec r$ is a **line integral**.  So you might think that we should use Stokes' theorem, except that $L$ is *not a closed curve*.  Thus Stokes' theorem does not apply.  So instead we just use one of the standard approachs to line integrals.  I give one in the comments above.  Here's another:

### One Form Method

First we find $\vec F\cdot d\vec r$.

$$\begin{align}\vec F\cdot d\vec r &= \big(yz(2x+y+z)\hat i+xz(x+2y+z)\hat j+xy(x+y+2z)\hat k\big)\cdot (dx\hat i + dy\hat j + dz\hat k) \\ &= yz(2x+y+z)dx+xz(x+2y+z)dy+xy(x+y+2z)dz\end{align}$$

Then we restrict this to the line $L$ by composing the one-form with the curve over which we're integrating $\vec \gamma(t) = \color{red}{3\cos(t)}\hat i + \color{purple}{4\sin(t)}\hat j +\color{blue}{t^2}\hat k$:

$$\begin{align}(\vec F\cdot d\vec r)\circ \vec \gamma(t) &= \color{purple}{(4\sin(t))}\color{blue}{(t^2)}(2\color{red}{(3\cos(t))}+\color{purple}{(4\sin(t))}+\color{blue}{(t^2)})d\color{red}{(3\cos(t))} \\ &\ \ \ \ +\color{red}{(3\cos(t))}\color{blue}{(t^2)}(\color{red}{(3\cos(t))}+2\color{purple}{(4\sin(t))}+\color{blue}{(t^2)})d\color{purple}{(4\sin(t))} \\ &\ \ \ \ +\color{red}{(3\cos(t))}\color{purple}{(4\sin(t))}(\color{red}{(3\cos(t))}+\color{purple}{(4\sin(t))}+2\color{blue}{(t^2)})d\color{blue}{(t^2)} \\ &= 4t^2\sin(t)(6\cos(t)+4\sin(t)+t^2)(-3\sin(t))dt \\ &\ \ \ \ + 3t^2\cos(t)(3\cos(t)+8\sin(t)+t^2)(4\cos(t))dt \\ &\ \ \ \ + 12\cos(t)\sin(t)(3\cos(t)+4\sin(t)+2t^2)(2t)dt \\ &= \Big[-12t^2\sin^2(t)(6\cos(t)+4\sin(t)+t^2) \\ &\ \ \ \ \ \ + 12t^2\cos^2(t)(3\cos(t)+8\sin(t)+t^2) \\ &\ \ \ \ \ \ + 24t\cos(t)\sin(t)(3\cos(t)+4\sin(t)+2t^2)\Big]dt\end{align}$$

You can see above that I use the identity $df(t) = f'(t)dt$ to simplify expressions like $d(3\cos(t))$.

Now just simplify and integrate $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} (\vec F\cdot d\vec r)\circ \vec \gamma(t)$$ which is just a regular Riemann integral, where the bounds were chosen because $\vec \gamma(0) = (3,0,0)$ and $\vec \gamma(\frac{\pi}{2}) = (0,4,\frac{\pi^2}{4})$.

### Potential Function Method

Now for the way you should actually do it $\ddot \smile$.  We can check whether this function has a potential $\phi$.  That is, we want to know whether $\vec F = \nabla \phi$ for some $\phi$.

It turns out that in this case there is: $\phi(x,y,z) = x^2yz+xy^2z+xyz^2$.  I'll let you try to figure that part out yourself (if you can't let me know and I can edit it in).

Given that, we can directly apply the gradient theorem:

$$\int_L \nabla\phi\cdot d\vec r = \phi(p_2) -\phi(p_1)$$ where $p_1$ is the starting point and $p_2$ is the ending point along the curve.